# Downloads Folder Keeps Getting Grouped

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

After a Windows 10 update (Feature Update 1909), my Downloads folder was suddenly grouped (see image at bottom for an example) into days the items were downloaded.

I followed a tutorial to remove the grouping (right click in the folder, go to "Group By" and select "(None)") and thought that everything would be fine. Unfortunately, about once a day the Downloads folder will suddenly be grouped again.

Can anyone help me to make it so that my change to keep the Downloads folder ungrouped is permanent?

[image: Group headers in Downloads folder]
<sub>(Image cropped from [Techdows.com](https://techdows.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/downloads-folder-view-files-grouped-by-today-yesterday-min.png))</sub>

Comment: Please describe the process you used to change the view of those folders.  Should be as simple as right-click and and selecting **None**, honestly, you will have to provide more details about which update you installed.  be sure you edit your question instead of replying with a temporary comment

Comment: @Ramhound I updated my answer to show that that IS what I did. For some reason windows keeps undoing it.

Comment: After you change the view of the folder in question.  Have you hit "Apply to Folders" within the Options?  I am guessing you were NOT running 1903 before you upgraded to 1909?

Comment: @Ramhound I'll see if that does anything.

Comment: This seems to have gotten really bad with Win11 22H2. It now forces the idiotic grouping on sub folders, every time you create a new one. This folder has become impossible to work with...

Answer (score 9):

[One given answer](https://superuser.com/a/1742576/1735492) is close, but somehow the values given are inaccurate. I managed to get it work by doing the following (changed parts are stated in **bold**, as my reputation point is not enough to give a comment to that answer)

The regedit value to modify is under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`

The values to edit:

GroupBy > **System.Null**

SortByList > **prop:System.ItemNameDisplay**

(You may wish to change PrimaryProperty to `System.ItemNameDisplay` or `System.Null` also.)

Check [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-null) for the list of supported Windows Properties.

If there are any permission warning preventing you from editing the fields, change the ownership of `{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}` to you (your [object name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/orphan-topics/ws.11/dn789205(v=ws.11))) by right-clicking the folder label, and open the advanced security setting panel.

After that, all subdirectories with no previous settings will be sorted by name without grouping by default. You may wish to change the grouping settings of the Downloads in the Explorer if it was modified before.

An alternative to setting all folder view settings to the same thing when fixing the Downloads folder's view is the goal, per [this forum thread](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/136903-disable-group-set-default-none-windows-10-1903-a-2.html), is to remove the Downloads directory view settings:

```powershell
$Bags = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'
$DLID = '{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}'
(Get-ChildItem $bags -recurse | ? PSChildName -eq $DLID ) | Remove-Item
gps explorer | spps
```

Comment: This seems to work. I'm using Win11 22H2. One gotcha I've noticed is folders that existed before applying this change retain their last view state (even if you delete and recreate it with the same name). I think this makes sense because this answer updates a template which is used to init view settings; it doesn't edit already init'd view settings. I applied the changes in this answer and then ran the "Reset Folder View Settings to Default" steps from https://www.elevenforum.com/t/reset-folder-view-settings-to-default-in-windows-11-file-explorer.1279/ and all Download (sub-)folders are fixed.

Comment: Derp, I see the answer does address the "gotcha" I mentioned. Credit to TWY for pointing that out. Hopefully the second half of my comment is still helpful to apply the updated template to all Downloads folders, even those that exist already.

Comment: No need to take control of the entire {885...} key. All you need ownership of is the {000...} key. May not be a huge deal in this particular case, but it's never preferable to hijack established permissions where it's unnecessary.

Comment: I've tried this, and it's worked for me. I did take ownership of the `{885...}` key, because I didn't notice @arkon's comment, so I haven't tested whether thaking ownership of `{000...}` instead would suffice. Nevertheless, thank you @TWY!

Comment: *"After that, all subdirectories with no previous settings will be sorted by name without grouping by default."* I don't think this applies to subdirectories of folders with previous settings. I manually unset "Group By" in Downloads, and subfolders I create of it are still affected by this.

Answer (score 0):

this might be where the bug lies ... explorer might retain the 'last view' in the browse for 'download to' (save as) location view, of the most recent downloaded file, regardless of how many times you try to set it to 'no groups' manually afterwards, so ... try this ... download any file, and make sure that the 'save as' pop-up 'view' is grouped and sorted as you want in the 'Downloads Folder', and if it is not, then make those changes there, in that 'save as' view, before actually downloading the file.

Comment: I actually did that, but it sometimes it remembers and sometimes it spontaneously forgets. It was also doing it differently for when I looked at it when downloading a file and when just using windows explorer. It seems like it might have been mostly fixed in the subsequent updates, but it does revert back once in a blue moon.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a permanent fix that will default the Downloads folder (works for open/save dialogs) to simple alphabetical sorting (but you can tweak it to your liking).

In regedit, there are two values to modify under:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

GroupBy > System.None

SortByList > prop:System.Name

You might need to first take ownership of the parent folder `{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}` via right click > Permissions > Advanced before you can modify these values. It should work instantaneously.