# How can I disable grouping in the downloads folder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

On my new laptop I right-clicked in the downloads folder and turned off grouping.

Unfortunately, it's still getting grouped (by date), and **I get no option to turn it off again.** Is there something I can change in the registry, or is there some other way to turn this off?

I just want to sort by date when I click the date column, and by name when I click the name column.

Windows 10 Home, v2004, OS build 19041.1052

[image: os info and right-click menu]

Thanks for the suggestions.

I have not (knowingly) installed any third-party explorer apps.

Here's a new image, right-clicking on the blank area:

[image: righ-click on blank area]

I found 33 "desktop.ini" files; 30 of them are in this WinSxS directory:

[image: desktop.ini locations]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I rightclicked on the folder background, selected "Group By > (None)" and it works like any other folder.

Comment: Works fine for me too.

Comment: Working properly here as well. (a) Windows Explorer, downloads folder. View tab and check Group By. Is this set to Name or Category?  That may be a reason. (b) Have you installed a 3rd party Explorer App that "integrates" with Windows Explorer that is causing this?

Comment: I know all of us chiming in with "not happening here" is not fun, but me neither.  I doubt a third party plugin can change the view of this folder.. it looks like a bug to me.  Look for a hidden desktop.ini in that folder that might somehow be overriding your settings.. Otherwise.. I sure don't know without being able to troubleshoot this hands on.

Comment: Thanks; more information added to question.

Comment: The screenshot you added shows the **`(None)`** option in the context menu. Selecting that should turn off grouping. Then you you need to select `Folder Options` from the **View** Ribbon, select the **VIew** *tab* in the **Folder Optons** dialog, and use the **Apply to Folders** button to set the ungrouped view as the default for all folders that use the `Downloads` *FolderType*.

Comment: Wow, now I feel like an id10t. Thanks!

Comment: This answer helped me figure out how to disable "Group By" permanently: https://superuser.com/questions/1566886/downloads-folder-keeps-getting-grouped

Comment: I've tried the answer @MDMower links to, and can confirm it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the photo, you clicked on a *file*, since the option to *Open* is shown. Instead, right-click on a *blank* area of the right (detail) pane.

[image: Group-by options]

Yes, this is a pain, since the "feature" is somewhat obscure!

Comment: Thanks, screenshot posted in original question.

Comment: I don't find it obscure - your screenshot even shows an alternative way to access the group-by menu. Look at the Explorer menu bar `View` there is a `Group by` button which will open the same menu. There you can select `None`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems I was just clicking on the wrong area.