# Disable Group by in Downloads folder only (Windows 11 22H2)

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

With the latest Windows 11 update (22H2) they decided to group files by last modify date in the Downloads folder, no matter if you disable it by *right-clicking>Group by>(None)*, when creating a new folder it will be always affected by file grouping and there's no option to disable it in the folder properties. 
The only thing I can find online is *click the three horizontal dots>Options>View>Apply to Folders*, but when clicking on the 'Apply to Folders' button it asks you to confirm or cancel your choice, dispalying this message below: 
*Do you want all folders of this type to match this folder's view settings?* 
So by confirming, it sets those view options to all folders, not just to the Downloads folder and its sub-folders. 
Please help me, since I can find only that fix online, but actually it's not what I need, because I don't want to mess up with all other folders.

Comment: Are you using AVG?   A Microsoft thread suggested AVG was clearing out the change you make.  I do not seem to have this issue. Still testing

Comment: I have tested two Windows 11 22H2 machines and Downloads Group by (Not Grouped by) is the same as any other folder and I did not "Apply to all folders" for this test.

Comment: I was unable to recreate the behavior you described on any of my Windows 11 devices

Comment: Same here.  So @OP  - are you running AVG?  So the issue is not Windows and not Windows Updates.

Comment: It says "all folders of this type" or something to that effect. When you execute `Apply to Folders` from an Explorer window, it only affects the FolderType of that folder -- which is what you want. Even though it's not listed on the `Customize` tab in the folder Properties, it does exist.

Comment: You can verify you've custiomized the `Downloads FolderType` by checking for a value named `{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}` under the key: `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloads Folder Keeps Getting Grouped](https://superuser.com/questions/1566886/downloads-folder-keeps-getting-grouped)

Comment: AFAIR, there's a way to manage all of your custom views in `ps.exe`

Comment: [Found it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lO6ip591UYJOtR3Cr0Zkm3-6Jq3FsC0R/view)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to reproduce this behaviour, and fixed it by going to a subfolder in "Downloads", setting "Group By" to (None), then in Folder Options, I clicked "Apply to Folders". Strangely, I tried this a few months ago and it didn't work. Not sure what changed, it could be a Windows Update or maybe I set the view to "Details" instead of "List" or "Small icons".

My Downloads folder is a subfolder of Dropbox, this could have been related.

I tried using WinAero Tweaker to set this but didn't find such options. I would still recommend using it to disable internet search on the Start Menu.

Answer (score 1):

The "GroupBy Date"-enforced setting on the Downloads folder has constantly been frustrating to me, but this has been an issue long before Windows 11. Right-clicking and changing `Group By` works for a little while, but then it reverts back at random times.

(I'm assuming this is the issue you're having)

I did a little research, and found a regedit patch I tried that seems to work (hopefuly it *continues* to work). I'm using Windows 10, but it may work the same.

Since `{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}` is the Downloads FolderType CLSID, the offending registry key values are located here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

In these keys you'll see the unwanted settings:

```
...
GroupBy           System.DateModified
...
PrimaryProperty   System.DateModified
SortByList        prop:System.DateModified
```

Unfortunately by default, you won't have permission to modify them (even as admin). To modify them, you'll have to take ownership of them first:

- Right-click each `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` key and for each:
- Go to `Permissions`
- Click `Advanced`
- You'll see `Owner:` at the top is `System`. Click `Change`
- Type your username under `Enter the object name to select`
- Hit `Check names` to make it detect the full object name
- Hit `OK` to update the owner
- Hit `OK` to close `Advanced Security Settings`
- Assuming you're an Admin, select `Administrators` from under `Group or user names`
- Then check `Full Control` under `Permissions for Administrators`
- Finally hit `Apply` or `OK` to give yourself permissions

At this point, you can freely modify the keys and values.

---

##### Reg Installer: Disable Downloads Group-By

To make `Downloads` stop grouping by date, first **back up your existing keys** (right-click the `{0000...0000}` keys and hit `Export`). Then use the following .reg file, which deletes all the `GroupBy` values, and replaces the `SortByList` column with the item name (instead of date) for both locations:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; DISABLE GROUP-BY IN DOWNLOADS FOLDER

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}]
"GroupAscending"=-
"GroupBy"=-
"PrimaryProperty"=-
"SortByList"="prop:System.ItemNameDisplay"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}]
"GroupAscending"=-
"GroupBy"=-
"PrimaryProperty"=-
"SortByList"="prop:System.ItemNameDisplay"
```